# PHP Date difference (calendar control -> conversion in days)

Tags: php, date

I am currently trying to calculate the date difference with a PHP Script. The days are in a calendar control, while the time is in 2 dropboxes (hour/minute).

You can see [my demo form here](http://www.inchirieri.net/contact_seller/?listing_id=418).

I need the PHP script to return the date in days, using the following formula. 
If the difference between the dates is **> X days and more than 2 hours**, then the difference is X+1 days, otherwise it's X Days.

Could anybody provide a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

See the doc for [DateTime::diff / date_diff](http://mx.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) there is example too.

Comment: @inchirieri : be careful if you want use object DateTime => it's available only for PHP >= 5.3 !

Comment: @Corum I think the DateTime object mostly just wraps the "flat functions" which have been available for a long time...? Ie the man topic I linked has a info about both obj and func.